# Difficulty in deploying android application

Tags: android

```
Getting Error message:: (All Error I can not Copy & pest bcoz of code size restictions)

    Starting deploy MyEmulator ...
    Deploying MyEmulator ...
    Build started.
      End of inner exception stack trace
```

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.InstallPackageAssemblies.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
     (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploymentException: InternalError ---> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: 
       at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
       at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass90_0.b__0(Task`1 t)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__99.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.d__98.MoveNext()<---

```
Build FAILED.
An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
Build started.
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;__XAMARIN_ANDROID_v1_0__;__MOBILE__;__ANDROID__;__ANDROID_1__;__ANDROID_2__;__ANDROID_3__;__ANDROID_4__;__ANDROID_5__;__ANDROID_6__;__ANDROID_7__;__ANDROID_8__;__ANDROID_9__;__ANDROID_10__;__ANDROID_11__;__ANDROID_12__;__ANDROID_13__;__ANDROID_14__;__ANDROID_15__;__ANDROID_16__;__ANDROID_17__;__ANDROID_18__;__ANDROID_19__;__ANDROID_20__;__ANDROID_21__;__ANDROID_22__;__ANDROID_23__ /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Java.Interop.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference MainActivity.cs Resources\Resource.Designer.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "C:\Users\ITC\AppData\Local\Temp\MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Debug\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
App1 -> C:\Users\ITC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\bin\Debug\App1.dll
  Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
:Deployment failed
    ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========


    Emulator screen shows message][2]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqp4.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX3MO.png
```

Comment: please follow this steps http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please Guide me.... anyone.  Output window shows -> Emulator Deploying and then throws error -> Process system is not responding.   Emulator I am using attached with question message(2) and error attached message(1).

Comment: actually i didn’t understand your problem exactly

Comment: and you are using xamrin and you didnt define tag od xamrin so no one understand your question for which one

Comment: Trying to deploy simple hello world..! application on emulator.
Emulator starts successfully. but while deploying app on emulator -> starts build and then throws error "Process system is not responding"
Please Help me out of this.
I have done xamarin installation manually. (jdk-8u102-windows-i586 using) and emulator using attached file(2)

Comment: using visual studio 2015

Comment: but yr i am not aware  about xamrin so